# How can I get my ColdFusion webservice to consume UTF-8?

Tags: http, unicode, utf-8, coldfusion

I have a very simple ColdFusion web app that takes one URL parameter and prints it to the page. But it doesn't seem to be receiving a UTF-8 encoded value, even though it's sent that way.

Here's an HTTP request, taken from Fiddler:

```
POST http://blahblahwebservice/getme.htm HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: unicode_post
Host: miscmsuatsw
Content-Length: 14  
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: CFID=247445; CFTOKEN=305db8322d5cecfb-627BD26F-BC91-0EC2-25E9745308EF96F7

sysopts=ΠΣΩ
```

Here's what it looks like in HEX (URL & HTTP/1.1 with 2 CRLFs & host stripped):

```
43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70 65 3A 20 61 70     Content-Type: ap
70 6C 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 78 2D 77 77 77 2D     plication/x-www-
66 6F 72 6D 2D 75 72 6C 65 6E 63 6F 64 65 64 3B     form-urlencoded;
20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3D 55 54 46 2D 38 0D 0A      charset=UTF-8..
55 73 65 72 2D 41 67 65 6E 74 3A 20 75 6E 69 63     User-Agent: unic
6F 64 65 5F 70 6F 73 74 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A 20     ode_post..Host: 
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0D 0A 43 6F 6E     .............Con
74 65 6E 74 2D 4C 65 6E 67 74 68 3A 20 31 34 0D     tent-Length: 14.
0A 50 72 61 67 6D 61 3A 20 6E 6F 2D 63 61 63 68     .Pragma: no-cach
65 0D 0A 43 6F 6F 6B 69 65 3A 20 43 46 49 44 3D     e..Cookie: CFID=
32 34 37 34 34 35 3B 20 43 46 54 4F 4B 45 4E 3D     247445; CFTOKEN=
33 30 35 64 62 38 33 32 32 64 35 63 65 63 66 62     305db8322d5cecfb
2D 36 32 37 42 44 32 36 46 2D 42 43 39 31 2D 30     -627BD26F-BC91-0
45 43 32 2D 32 35 45 39 37 34 35 33 30 38 45 46     EC2-25E9745308EF
39 36 46 37 0D 0A 0D 0A 73 79 73 6F 70 74 73 3D     96F7....sysopts=
CE A0 CE A3 CE A9                                   Î Î£Î©
```

Specifically, **`ΠΣΩ`** is **`CE A0 CE A3 CE A9`**.

When rendered, I merely get "???". I know that the page can render utf-8, I think it's in the reception of these bytes because when I set the UTF-8 hex chars to `U+03A0` and so fort, it renders just fine.

Is there something my CF webpage is missing in order to handle UTF-8??

Comment: 0xCEA0 is UTF-8 and 0x03A0 is Unicode / UTF-16. So it seems you're having an encoding issue on the display side. Are you on Windows? I seem to remember that the console is by default UTF-16...

Comment: I'm on windows, using `CT2A(CP_UTF8, sMyString)` in my MFC C++ app. The encoding is perfectly fine. It is most definitely the receiving end of the ColdFusion service. I made my own demo cfm and it worked fine, so the service I'm working with has a bug.

Comment: Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853622/whats-the-difference-between-using-form-and-gethttprequestdata-with-regar

Comment: the HTTP request body is incorrect; non-ASCII characters need to be %-encoded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">` on the first line of your CFM.

If it works, you should switch to editor like CF Builder, where the BOM stamp will take care of that and no processing directive needed.

Comment: @MikCaron send from what? CFHTTP?  I'm not sure why they're encoded,  could it be your monitor tool that's doing the converting?

Comment: So I downloaded CF 10 Developer version and created a small test CFM that reads from the request variables. I stuck that line a the top and voila, it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting ColdFusion to "think harder" about them being utf-8 by using the [`setEncoding`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1fb12-7fcb.html) function.

```
<cfscript>
    SetEncoding("url", "utf-8");
    SetEncoding("form", "utf-8");
</cfscript>
```

Unless you're doing something exceptionally specialised, those two lines should always be in your `Application.cfm/c`.

The tag `cfprocessingdirective` is only of benefit if you have utf-8 characters in the `.cfm` file itself.  UTF-8 encoded strings that come from url/form/cookie/database, etc do not fall into that category, and therefore won't be affected by that tag.

Comment: "Use this function when the character encoding of the input to a form or the character encoding of a URL is *not* in UTF-8 encoding" hmm... http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1fb12-7fcb.html

Comment: @Henry What are you hmming?  As per your comment above "could it be your monitor tool that's doing the converting" which would imply that it's not UTF-8 to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Also, every application/system has its own set or default encoding - this includes your web server, your db server, your browser, your db front-end, your editor. All of those things need to be checked before ruling out the obvious.

Also try this to see what you get.

```
<cfscript>
    ....
    charencode=CharsetEncode(yourstuffgoeshere, "UTF-8");
    WriteOutput("<br />" & charencode);
</cfscript>
```

I am curious as to whether your data is actually binary data. If so, this will encode it for you. But the recommended approach is to check your browser, server,etc

Faith Sloan

Comment: Browser doesn't even come into play. I'm using a command line client built by me with VC++ & MFC to make the HTTP connection and send the data. I've grabbed the raw bytes using both fiddler & wireshark to make sure that what I'm sending is correctly encoded UTF-8 Unicode text.

Comment: I tried `<cfdump var=#CharsetEncode(form.a,'utf-8')# label='dbg'>` to no avail :(