# What's the difference between using #form# and #getHttpRequestData()# with regard to charset?

Tags: http, coldfusion, localhost

I have a coldfusion page, uni.cfm:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
<cfscript>

<cfdump var="#form.a#" label="form">
<cfdump var="#getHttpRequestData().content#" label="form2">
```

Sending the following HTTP request produces in the returned html first the string `"???"`, then the string `"a=ΠΣΩ"`.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/uni/unicode.cfm HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: unicli
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 8
Pragma: no-cache

a=ΠΣΩ
```

Why does #form.a# NOT process the binary string correctly, while getHttpRequestData() does?

Comment: That's a great question but your first CFDUMP should be "#form.a#".

Comment: This bugging me too :) What happens when you "view source" - maybe it's CFDUMP that's crossing you up. In second instance you are getting the raw "unvarnished" version.. perhaps the CSS and behavior stuff in cfdump is what is mangling it in the first instance. IN the second instance it's pretty "plain jane" so it's getting the right cascade of dom properties to work with?

Comment: What is the purpose of the SetEncoding directive on the form?  What is the incoming encoding? (getEncoding(form))?

Comment: @Sharondio no purpose. I just took it out and it was the same result. The form is already using UTF-8.

Comment: The weird part is that if I send the data in URL-encoded hex, like %CE%A3, etc. Form.a picks up the unicode. That's an ASCII-encoded representation of UTF-8. I've noticed that if I use CF to post the data that it uses that method. So is the data in form.a not raw bytes?

Comment: Is the form variable only able to understand form values that were passed in via a CF form?

Comment: Maybe it is because of `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and that means the content is `urlencoded`, not binary?  I'm not sure.  However, if `getHttpRequestData()` works for you, use that.

Comment: Henry, that's it! Instead of sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded, I switched to multipart/form-data and voila!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the sender change content-type to `multipart/form-data` with NO url-encoding worked like a charm:

```
POST *URL* HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x
Content-Length: 145

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="a"

ΠΣΩ
--AaB03x--
```

Then able to use #form.a# and get the right string!