# ColdFusion and Unicode Characters Issues

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, coldfusion

Working on the Globalization of the Coldfusion website using the i18n.

I am using the resource files rather than database..

In my one of the string files, i have the value being displayed as:

```
Inicia sesión con tu nombre de usuario y contraseña.
```

and when i run on my browser, it is displayed as:

```
Inicia sesi�n con tu nombre de usuario y contrase�a.
```

Having read the below link, i have enabled the `utf` through `cfprocessingdirective` and the meta tag also, but i am not sure why it is still displaying it like this.

[ColdFusion character encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485224/coldfusion-character-encoding-issue)

I used the Google translate to translate the above English to Spanish.

Using this in my Application.cf  also:

```
<cfset setLocale("English (US)")>
  <!--- Set the session page encoding --->
  <cfset setencoding("URL", "utf-8")>
  <cfset setencoding("Form", "utf-8")>
```

**Update #1**

I cannot Update, but i am adding here: 
spanish:

```
username=Nombre de usuario
login=Inicia sesión con tu nombre de usuario y contraseña.
appName=Inventory Manager
rem=Acuérdate de mí
slogin=Iniciar sesión
errorLoginMsg=Error! Credenciales de login fallidos, Inténtalo de nuevo
ser='Nombre de usuario' es un campo obligatorio.
ser1='Password' es un campo obligatorio.
nitem=Nuevo elemento
ilist=Lista de artículos
order=Orden
olist=Lista de Pedidos
sell=Vender
slist=Lista de Ventas
quote=Cotizaciones
qlist=Lista Cotizaciones
rs=Vuelto Vendido
inv=Factura
```

Russian File it is ru.rtf

```
username=Имя пользователя
login=Войти с именем пользователя и паролем.
appName=Inventory Manager
rem=Запомнить меня
slogin=войти
errorLoginMsg=Ошибка! Учетные данные для входа не удалась, попробуйте еще ​​раз
ser='Имя' является обязательным полем.
ser1=Поле 'Пароль' является обязательным.
nitem=Новый элемент
ilist=Список статей
order=Заказать
olist=Список Заказать
sell=Продать
slist=Список продажам
quote=Цитаты
qlist=Котировки Список
rs=Продано Возвращается
inv=Счет
```

Comment: When you say "string file" do you mean it's some sort of data file you read in? Or is it a CFM file, or what? Can you pls post the code that is causing the problem (just the relevant parts)

Comment: answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10839911/35634

Comment: I am using the resource files as: en.strings, es.strings, ru.strings etc. But i have seen that if i try adding russian in the ru.strings, it just displays question marks only, so i saved it as ru.rtf which has actually the russian characters in those, i will attach bot the files here in my main question

Comment: @Henry, I think i included your answer link in my question, Thanks for pointing though

Comment: OK, so how are you reading those files in? I'm gonna be offline for the next 4, but I suspect you need to read the docs for `fileRead()` (https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/FileRead), and pay attention to the `charset` argument.

Comment: yes, the charset is passed properly, i checked that

Comment: OK, as I said before, pls stop describing your code and just show it to us! Give us a pared-down repro case that demonstrates what you're seeing. Pare it back to *only* what#'s necessary to demonstrate the problem.  Which would basically be a file-read and an output statement.

Comment: *i have enabled the utf through cfprocessingdirective* [cfprocessingdirective is only of benefit if you have utf-8 characters in the .cfm file itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10841869/104223). That said, without a repro case, all we can do is guess here .. Help us to help you. Can you please post your code?

Comment: I solved it, i used the EmEditor and saved the file as Utf-8 with Signarture and it worked, so from my end, i think coldfusion did not did anything wrong, it was just the character encoding how the file was saved where translation was written

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but next time please include a complete repro case **with the initial question**. You almost certainly would have received an answer days ago, had it been included from the beginning, instead of people having to ask for it ...